# Adding <!DOCTYPE html> removes my container background

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a website as a first year project, this is our first website that we need to make but i found out that we were supposed to use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of `<html>` (which was told later on) but now that i do that, the background of my container/content div disappears and only shows a bit when i put a letter inside of it.

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 1px;
 min-width: 1px;
}

html {
 height: 100%;
}

#nav {
 width: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(#009940, #009900, #009800);
}

#nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#nav li  {
 float: left;
}

#nav li a {
 display: block;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 14px 18px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 
#nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #396108;
 }
 
#nav li a img {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -0.4%;
 margin-left: -0.7%;
}

#container {
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 vertical-align: top;
}


#container #header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 3%;
 background: linear-gradient(#009940, #008000, #009800); 
}

#container #header p {
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.4em; 
 padding-top: 0.5%;
}

#content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.textClass {
 border: 2px solid black;
 margin-top: 7.5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 width: 40%;
 height: 20.7%;
 background-color: white;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
 }
 
.textClass img {
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 transition:height 0s 10000s;
}

.textClass p {
 padding-top: 0.5%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.gallery {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 9%;
 margin-left: 9%;
}

.gallery:hover img {
 transform: scale(1);
 transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}

.gallery img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.75);
}

footer {
 background-color: #009902;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 0;
 color: white;
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Interreses - Website</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/Logo.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/interreses.html">Interreses</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Groepsleden.html">Groepsleden</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Opleiding.html">Opleiding</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fotogalerij.html">Fotogalerij</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><a style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" href="/index.html"><img src="/images/logo.png"></img></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <p style="text-align: center;"> Interesses </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div style="width: 60%; height: 70%; margin-left: 19%; margin-top: 12%;" class="textClass">
      <p style="font-size: 1.2em; text-align: center;">Ik ben geinterreseerd in Gamen, Programmeren en Video Editing, ik zal ook uitleggen waarom.<br>
        <br>
      </p>
      <img src="/images/Gamen.jpg"/>
      <p style="font-size: 1.2em;">Gamen is leuk om te doen in mijn vrije tijd, ik hoop dan ook wel minimaal 60 uur per twee weken aan gamen besteed, bijvoorbeeld: <br>
        Gta V: 50 Uren <br>
        Cs:Go: 193 Uren <br>
        Age of empires 2: 71 Uren <br>
        Skyrim: 41 Uren <br>
        Garry's mod: 16 Uren<br>
      </p>
      <img src="/images/Programmeren.jpg"/>
      <p style="font-size: 1.2em;">Programmeren is ook een hobby van mij, ik programmeer meestal in Java maar nu ook in Javascipt, HTML5 en CSS3, dit kon ik overigens wel al, maar ik heb het lang niet meer <br>
        Java: 3 jaar <br>
        HTML: 1/2-1 jaar <br>
        CSS3: 1/2-1 jaar <br>
        Javascript: 1-4 maanden<br>
      </p>
      <img src="/images/Java.png"/>
      <p style="font-size: 1.2em;"><br>
        Java is mijn favoriete taal waar ik later ook een baan mee wil krijgen <br>
        ik programmeer al 3 jaar java, bijvoorbeeld: <br>
        Enumeratie, Abstracte classes <br>
        Interfaces en objecten <br>
        en nog veel meer, meestal programmeer ik plugins voor games bijvoorbeeld Maple Story, Rune Scape en Minecraft </p>
      <img style="margin-left: -27%; margin-top: 7%;" src="/images/VidEdit.jpg"/>
      <p style="font-size: 1.2em; margin-top: 7%;"><br>
        Video Editing deed ik erg vaak, nu niet meer maar het was wel een leuke tijdbesteding van mij <br>
        MLG compilatie filmpjes maken en ze daarna weer verwijderen <br>
        ik deed het video editing puur om het editen dus ik heb dus overige data want mijn PC is gereset<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<footer id="footer" style="margin-left: 0; color: white; width: 70%; margin-left: 15%;">Copyright by ******** (C) 2016-2019</footer>
</html>
```

The background of the content/container should be light gray

Comment: You define `#content`, but there is no element with `id="content"`...

Comment: btw... `<footer>` should be inside the `<body>`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I cut that out by accident when putting it on here, sorry for that

Comment: You're supposed to use the doctype *in addition to* the <html> start tag, not instead of. Also, why on earth were you only told this later on. This should have been taught right from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the other answers you still need the `<html>` tag. Footer you said was by accident outside the body but I placed it inside the body in the snippet below. One way to get your elements flowing correctly in your HTML structure is to set `float: left;` to your `#content` div.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  min-width: 1px;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#009940, #009900, #009800);
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #396108;
}
#nav li a img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -0.4%;
  margin-left: -0.7%;
}
#container {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#container #header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3%;
  background: linear-gradient(#009940, #008000, #009800);
}
#container #header p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.textClass {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 7.5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20.7%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.textClass img {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  transition: height 0s 10000s;
}
.textClass p {
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.gallery {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9%;
  margin-left: 9%;
}
.gallery:hover img {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}
.gallery img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.75);
}
footer {
  background-color: #009902;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>Interreses - Website</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/Logo.ico" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/interreses.html">Interreses</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/Groepsleden.html">Groepsleden</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/Opleiding.html">Opleiding</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/fotogalerij.html">Fotogalerij</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float: right;">
        <a style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" href="/index.html">
          <img src="/images/logo.png" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <p style="text-align: center;">Interesses</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div style="width: 60%; height: 70%; margin-left: 19%; margin-top: 12%;" class="textClass">
        <p style="font-size: 1.2em; text-align: center;">Ik ben geinterreseerd in Gamen, Programmeren en Video Editing, ik zal ook uitleggen waarom.
          <br>
          <br>
        </p>
        <img src="/images/Gamen.jpg" />
        <p style="font-size: 1.2em;">Gamen is leuk om te doen in mijn vrije tijd, ik hoop dan ook wel minimaal 60 uur per twee weken aan gamen besteed, bijvoorbeeld:
          <br>Gta V: 50 Uren
          <br>Cs:Go: 193 Uren
          <br>Age of empires 2: 71 Uren
          <br>Skyrim: 41 Uren
          <br>Garry's mod: 16 Uren
          <br>
        </p>
        <img src="/images/Programmeren.jpg" />
        <p style="font-size: 1.2em;">Programmeren is ook een hobby van mij, ik programmeer meestal in Java maar nu ook in Javascipt, HTML5 en CSS3, dit kon ik overigens wel al, maar ik heb het lang niet meer
          <br>Java: 3 jaar
          <br>HTML: 1/2-1 jaar
          <br>CSS3: 1/2-1 jaar
          <br>Javascript: 1-4 maanden
          <br>
        </p>
        <img src="/images/Java.png" />
        <p style="font-size: 1.2em;">
          <br>Java is mijn favoriete taal waar ik later ook een baan mee wil krijgen
          <br>ik programmeer al 3 jaar java, bijvoorbeeld:
          <br>Enumeratie, Abstracte classes
          <br>Interfaces en objecten
          <br>en nog veel meer, meestal programmeer ik plugins voor games bijvoorbeeld Maple Story, Rune Scape en Minecraft</p>
        <img style="margin-left: -27%; margin-top: 7%;" src="/images/VidEdit.jpg" />
        <p style="font-size: 1.2em; margin-top: 7%;">
          <br>Video Editing deed ik erg vaak, nu niet meer maar het was wel een leuke tijdbesteding van mij
          <br>MLG compilatie filmpjes maken en ze daarna weer verwijderen
          <br>ik deed het video editing puur om het editen dus ik heb dus overige data want mijn PC is gereset
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer" style="margin-left: 0; color: white; width: 70%; margin-left: 15%;">Copyright by ******** (C) 2016-2019</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can i get the content pane to go further than it is now? I need it to go under the .textClass bar straight to the footer, but i don't like to end it right after the .textClass has ended

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you could add `padding-bottom: 12%;` (12% is the margin you use on top with the `.textClass` div) or what ever value you'd like to the `#content` CSS. OR you could add `margin-bottom: 12%;` to the `.textClass` div.

Answer (score 2):

Niet beat me to it in the comments on your post but `#content` isn't defined anywhere in your html. I'm assuming that the div with the textClass class is what you want the content to be so just add it to that div as you've done above.

Some other minor points:

- You still need the opening `<html>` tag under your `!DOCTYPE` definition
- `<footer>` should be inside `<body>` with everything else
- I'd recommend setting those repeated `<p>` styles in your main content to a containing div such as the offending `#content` id. The styles will still be pulled through as they are now.

Answer (score 1):

ID content is missing, but i've made some simple changes in css. Is this what you are looking for?

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  min-width: 1px;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#009940, #009900, #009800);
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav li  {
  float: left;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #396108;
}
#nav li a img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -0.4%;
  margin-left: -0.7%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
#container #header {
  width: 70%;
  height: 3%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient(#009940, #008000, #009800); 
}
#container #header p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  padding-top: 0.5%;
}
.textClass {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 7.5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20.7%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.textClass img {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  transition:height 0s 10000s;
}
.textClass p {
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.gallery {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9%;
  margin-left: 9%;
}
.gallery:hover img {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}
.gallery img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.75);
}
footer {
  background-color: #009902;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The !doctype html tells your html page which version of HTML are you using.By default , it is the latest version that is HTML 5.
Now, html  /html these tags define the starting and ending of your html page.
These are mandatory tags for your HTML page. 
And in addition to these tags you use !doctype html tag.
Hope this helps you .

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
```

does not replace the `<html>` tag.  You need both, see http://www.w3ctutorial.com/tags/tag_doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
...
</html>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Hey, W3Tutorial, haven't seen that one before. Sounds suspiciously familiar. Their logo looks suspiciously familiar too. Oh well, not your fault. By the way, the `<html>` start tag is actually optional.

Comment: Fair, it may be optional, but it certainly isn't replaced by the doctype.  And keeping the close tag and css reference but stripping the open tag is not an option.

Comment: I agree that the doctype declaration and the <html> start tag are not interchangeable, as the OP seemed to think. However, both tags are optional. You can omit either one, or both, and it won't be an error. Also, omitting the start tag does not omit the whole element. It is still there and it can still be addressed with CSS and JavaScript; test for yourself. And this is not the browser doing its error handling; this is a basic definition of HTML and how parsing is done.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line after your `<body>`

```
    <div id="content">
```

and then make sure to close the div before `</body>`

As Niet pointed out, you were lacking an element with the id of 'content'